# Extracting actual values from a predicted plot in R

Tags: r, plot

Using Time series forecasting , I tried to predict the sales of a particular item.I  have got the required predicted plot . I want to extract the exact value from the plot. i.e I have the values from 2011-2016.Using time series forecasting I predicted the values for 2016-2020, but it's in the form of a plot.How to extract the predicted values from the plot?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have `prediction<-predict(model,...)`
then the values should be accessible through

```
prediction$values
```

or post a screen of `str(your_object)` and it will be clear from there.

Comment: Thanks for you response.                                                                                       > acf(diff(log(sales)))
> pacf(diff(log(sales)))
> fit <- arima(log(sales),c(0, 1, 1),seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 1), period = 12))
> pred <- predict(fit,n.ahead = 10*12)
> ts.plot(sales,2.718^pred$pred,log = "y", lty = c(1,3))
> pred$values
NULL
This is the code I used. After pred$values , I am getting the output as NULL.

Comment: Was it helpful? Could you please mark my answer as accepted then, please? Thanks

Comment: Then what you're looking or is in pred$pred. 

It will pop out:


`
     > p$pred
Time Series:
Start = 101 
End = 110 
Frequency = 1 
[1] -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109
 [9] -0.7636109 -0.7636109
> as.vector(p$pred)
 [1] -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109 -0.7636109
 [9] -0.7636109 -0.7636109' `

Comment: Thanks Jan. Your answer was immensely helpful.

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck:)